# How to resume picturebox image's gif winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

When a specific condition is met I disable my picturebox and the image freeze's, whenever it runs again the gif starts all over again not from where it was stopped is there anyway to resume it ?

Stopping picturebox :  http://prntscr.com/b6gg7a
"Resuming" picturebox : http://prntscr.com/b6gglb

Comment: This seems unlikely.

Comment: It's really annoying me and I have no idea how to fix it, please any tips are appreciated @TaW

Comment: This is a sidescroller game? You want the background to freeze whenever you stop moving forward. Right?

Comment: The cranky way to stop it is a hint how little support there is for animated gif. If you really really really need it and really really...... want to use GIFs you could try to a) find a way to determine the frame you have stopped at and then b) re-create the gif in a new order, starting from that frame.. A PITA, obviously, especially as part a) is not even very clear. (Embed markers and search for them in a screenshot? Argggh)

Comment: It's only one; nothing to think about..

Answer (score -1):

I believe indeed this is a rather tedious/unlikely to perform with an animated gif.

What you could/should do IMO is the following:

Instead of making the background a gif, break it into multiple frames(pictures).
Set up a timer that triggers the background to change to the next image.
You can pause and resume that timer the same as you would enable and disable the picturebox.

Your background change function could look something like this:

```
int bgCount = 8; //Amount of frames your background uses
int bgCurrent = 0;
string[] bgImg = {
    "bg1.png",
    "bg2.png",
    "bg3.png",
    "bg4.png",
    "bg5.png",
    "bg6.png",
    "bg7.png",
    "bg8.png",
};
        void changeBG()
{
    if(bgCurrent > bgCount-1) //If not displaying the last background image go to the next one
    {
        bgCurrent++;
        imgBox.image = bgImg[bgCurrent];
    }else //If displaying the last background image -> Start with the first one
    {
        bgCurrent = 0;
        imgBox.image = bgImg[bgCurrent];
    }
}
}
```

And you just let the timer trigger this event. And you simply start and stop the timer.

Sidenote:

1* You might experiment with, instead of changing the source, just make 8 imageboxed and call/display them as they are needed.

Comment: I already tried that it was answered here on stackoverflow by another user however it was even worse.

Comment: How can this be even worse?
This is basicly exploding the gif and glueing it back together withing c#?
Or was it worse in runtime, like not fluent, like it needs to much resources?

Comment: Actually using a gif is a clever idea: It can display rather fluently as opposed to the internal animation with winforms and its insteady and jumpy performance. But not all clever ideas work all the way through..